# JavaFx - How can I run a process AFTER form has been loaded

Tags: javafx

I want to build a console application that gets updated when a step of the process is finished.

I've got the process running but what I can not figure is how to start the process AFTER the form has been already built (showing) and is ready for input. At this point,as each step is complete a message is appended to the TextArea. Like a console.

All I got is the screen already completed by the steps of the process when the form shows up. And I want the form (TextArea) to be updated by a text at the end of each step of the process, which is a export of data.

I tried Platform.runLater, pre processor, events,Stage.showAndWait (I got an error) and I can not find the right answer.

In .Net this was covered by the FORM COMPLETE Event.

But nothing will be processed until the form was complete, which is really frustrating.

---

This is the Method - MAIN:

```
public class Main extends Application {
    
    public static MainSceneController cfgForm;
    public static Scene FormScene;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------|-------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Set the application's Icon
            try {
                Image imageIcon = new Image(getClass().getResource("/Resources/moneydance_icon512.png").toURI().toString());
                primaryStage.getIcons().add(imageIcon);
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        // -------------------------------------------------------------------|-------------------------------------------------------------------    // -------------------------------------------------------------------|-------------------------------------------------------------------    // -------------------------------------------------------------------|-------------------------------------------------------------------// -------------------------------------------------------------------|-------------------------------------------------------------------    // -------------------------------------------------------------------|-------------------------------------------------------------------    // -------------------------------------------------------------------|-------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Open Forms           
            primaryStage.setTitle("Export to MySQL");
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("MainScene.fxml"));
            Parent root = loader.load();
            cfgForm = loader.getController();  // <--- This is for later use

            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);    
            primaryStage.show();
            
//       testProcess(); // This is the dummy process I want to run after the form is loaded and ready.
        
    }
    public static void testProcess() {
        for (int index = 0; index < 6; index++) {
            try {
                // This ismulates the end of the different stages of the process
                cfgForm.set_tfOutPut(index + "   dssdfsdfsadfsdaf\n");
                System.out.println(index);
                
                /*
                 * <-- The following is only to simulate 
                 * the running of a single step in the 
                 * whole process
                 */
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the CONTROLLER Method:

```
public class MainSceneController {
    Stage stage = this.stage;
    @FXML    private Button btnOK;
    @FXML    private AnchorPane fMonitorProcess;
    @FXML    private ImageView iImage;
    @FXML    private TextArea tfOutPut;
    @FXML    private TextField txtTitle;
   
    @FXML
    void btnOKClicked(ActionEvent event) {
        stage = ((Stage) fMonitorProcess.getScene().getWindow());
        stage.close();
    }
    @FXML
    void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
        if(event.getCode()==KeyCode.ESCAPE){
            stage = (Stage) fMonitorProcess.getScene().getWindow();
            stage.close();
        } 
    }
    
    public void set_tfOutPut (String NewText) {
        this.tfOutPut.appendText(NewText);
    }

}
```

This is how the form looks:

[Target Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Te7LA.png)

Just a simple console application....

Comment: You have too much functionality in your `Application` class. I'm not sure what you're actually trying to do here, but assuming you want `xxx()` to be executed after the form has been completed: Move the `xxx()` method (why is it static? that makes no sense) to the controller and call it from the `btnOKClicked()` and/or `keyPressed()` method(s) as needed. You *must not* sleep on the FX Application Thread.

Comment: I want xxx to run automatically, once the Form is completed.

Comment: PS: During my tests I tried to put the construction of the form in another method to see if that worked, I just haven't move it back.

Comment: The sleep is to simulate the pause while the export program completes.

Comment: So, this app (shown here) is just a test to look for a solution to be able to run a method automatically without human intervention AFTER the form is ready, while showing the user how the process is going: eg: account table export completed or transaction table exported

Comment: Word of advice: when writing Java code, you should generally adhere to the `camelCase` naming convention for methods. Your `OpenForm` method is an example of a method that does not adhere to this naming convention.

Comment: What does it mean to “ready a form”?  Is that some kind of long running process you are trying to do on the JavaFX thread?  For “account table export” for example, what does that?  Is it done on the JavaFX thread or do you make the JavaFX thread just sit and wait for whatever is doing it to complete?

Comment: I do not want to use the JavaFX Thread. I just want to the export process to run, after the form is ready, so the user is kept updated of what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do not want to use the JavaFX Thread. I just want to the export process to run, after the form is ready, so the user is kept updated of what is happening.

Here is a straightforward example of using a [`Task`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) to do this.

It does not use FXML as in your example code, but the use of FXML isn't really the issue here.

The issue is that you are trying to execute a long running process on the JavaFX UI thread, which freezes the UI.  Instead, spawn a new thread, run the long running process on that thread, and interface between the long running process and your JavaFX UI using JavaFX's in-built concurrency mechanisms.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ExportTaskApp extends Application {

    TextArea console = new TextArea();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        console.setEditable(false);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(console));
        primaryStage.show();

        export();
    }

    private void export() {
        ExportTask exportTask = new ExportTask();
        exportTask.messageProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newExportMessage) ->
                console.appendText(newExportMessage)
        );
        Thread exportThread =  new Thread(exportTask, "export-task");
        exportThread.setDaemon(true);
        exportThread.start();
    }

    public static final class ExportTask extends Task<Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void call() {
            for (int index = 0; index < 6; index++) {
                try {
                    if (isCancelled()) {
                        updateMessage("Cancelled");
                        break;
                    }

                    // This simulates the start of the
                    // different stages of the process
                    updateMessage("Stage: " + index + "\n");

                    /*
                     * <-- The following is only to simulate
                     * the running of a single step in the
                     * whole process
                     */
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    if (isCancelled()) {
                        updateMessage("Cancelled");
                    } else {
                        updateMessage("Interrupted");
                    }
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**FAQ**

> How can I detect that the form is loaded and ready (JavaFX Thread finished) so I can trigger the long process.....

There is no need to wait for some explicit event to start your process after a form has loaded.  Once you call `show()` on your stage, your UI is already displayed to the user, so you can just initiate the new thread that executes your long running process after the UI has been shown.

Similarly for an FXML loaded document there is no need to listen for an explicit loaded event (there is no such event).  The load call for FXML happens synchronously.  Once the document is loaded (e.g. a [load](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#load()) method has been called on the FXMLLoader), it will have associated the elements instantiated by the loader with a controller.

You can then get the controller from the loader and ask it to update its UI by invoking methods on the controller from:

- the listeners on Task properties like the:

  - message property
  - progress property
  - status property and event handlers
- or via `Platform.runLater` calls in the task.

Then you can run the new task on an appropriate thread, e.g. by using the `Thread.start()` API or the `Executors` framework.

> I've tried a Pre-loader, but (1) it uses the JavaFx thread and (2) it doesn't change the behaviour: it'll show the form when Everything is done.

A JavaFX Preloader is for a completely different purpose.  It is for managing long-running application startups, usually via a splash-screen.  It was largely created for applet or webstart deployment scenarios of large code bases over very slow network connections.  The Preloader concept and implementation is largely obsolete for use in most modern JavaFX applications.

> it shows a blank scene. Then you have to wait for the whole process to finish to actually see what happened.

You shouldn’t be doing long running work, sleeping, blocking I/O or busy waiting on the JavaFX thread, it will freeze the UI. I don’t know which of those things you are doing, but it is probably one of those. You probably want a concurrent `Task`, or something running in a thread that notifies of progress via `Platform.runLater`.

> I've also tried "Platform.runLater" but it waits for the whole process to finish to show the form.

Then you have a threading error in your code, you are still trying to run a long running process on the JavaFX thread rather than another thread.

> I need to run an export process that will send a message to the JavaFx form when a process has started or finished, so that the user is aware of what is happening.

The simple demo I provided in this answer shows how to do that.

> The solution didn't really solve my issue, but when I got a 100ms pause before the loop, it shows the form before actually starting the process.  I was looking to see how the form will start populating as the process move on, but the 1st time I see the form, it shows Stage 1 already being process.

That is because my example is set to start processing the background task as soon as it can, which means you won't see a delay in starting the task unless you artificially add one.  That could be done in the task itself rather than on the JavaFX app thread by sleeping the task, or by using a PauseTransition on the JavaFX application thread to delay starting the process thread.  I'm not sure why you want an artificial delay before starting the task, but I guess that is your requirement.

> when I close the application, does all the threads close correctly?

You have to define what "correctly" means in the context of the application and the process you are running.  What is correct for one app and process may not be correct for another.

The example marks the process thread as a [daemon](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#isDaemon()) thread.  This means that when other non-daemon threads (e.g. the JavaFX app thread or the main Java thread) exit, the VM will just exit, it won't wait for the process thread to complete.  That might be OK if the process is in the middle of updating your Twitter timeline which is already completely broken, but might not be OK if the process is part way through the shutdown procedure for your nuclear reactor.

More sophisticated shutdown methods will manage processing threads like this in an execution thread pool (usually generated by the Executors framework).  And then on the JavaFX Application `stop()` method, the application can gracefully initiate shutdown of the thread pool by invoking its shutdown method.  Usually aided by the thread itself understanding it has been interrupted or the task has been cancelled.  Fully describing how this might be done is outside the scope of this answer.

**Additional Resources**

- Study [concurrency in JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm).

Comment: Hi @jewelsea, thanks for getting this to me. It did explain very well the concepts behind threads. The solution didn't really solve my issue, but when I got a 100ms pause before the loop, it shows the form before actually starting the process. I was looking to see how the form will start populating as the process move on, but the 1st time I see the form, it shows Stage 1 already being process. 

Nevertheless, I not only got it, but it opens a new way at looking at this. 

One last question, when I close the application, does all the threads close correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this answer may help. I think you should be using `Task` or `Service`. That depends on your situation ([more info](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm)). If you use `Task` or `Service`, you can use `setOnSucceeded`.

---

**Main**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * JavaFX App
 */
public class App extends Application {
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        try 
        {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("primary.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            
            stage.setTitle("FXML Welcome");
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
        } 
        catch (IOException ex) 
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

---

**PrimaryController**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

public class PrimaryController {
    @FXML StackPane spSubsceneHolder;
    @FXML TextArea taConsole;
    @FXML Button btnPrimaryView;
    
    VBox vbFirstsubsceneRoot;
    VBox vbSecondsubsceneRoot;
            
    //DataModel model; 
    public void initialize()
    {
        //Load model if needed!
        //model = new DataModel;
        loadFirstsubsceneController();
        
        btnPrimaryView.setText("Submit Form!");
    }
    
    public void loadFirstsubsceneController()
    {
        try 
        {
            FXMLLoader firstsubsceneLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("firstsubscene.fxml"));
            
            vbFirstsubsceneRoot = firstsubsceneLoader.load();
            spSubsceneHolder.getChildren().clear();
            spSubsceneHolder.getChildren().add(vbFirstsubsceneRoot);
            //Pass data if needed!!!
            //FirstsubsceneController firstsubsceneController = firstsubsceneLoader.getController();
            //firstsubsceneController.initModel(model);
            
            taConsole.setText("First subscene loaded!\n");
            //Or bind taConsole if needed!!!            
        } 
        catch (IOException ex) 
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public void loadSecondsubsceneController()
    {   try 
        {            
            FXMLLoader secondsubsceneLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("secondsubscene.fxml"));
            
            vbSecondsubsceneRoot = secondsubsceneLoader.load();
            spSubsceneHolder.getChildren().clear();
            spSubsceneHolder.getChildren().add(vbSecondsubsceneRoot);
            //Pass data if needed!!!
            //FirstsubsceneController firstsubsceneController = firstsubsceneLoader.getController();
            //firstsubsceneController.initModel(model);
            
            taConsole.setText("Second subscene loaded!\n");
            //Or bind taConsole if needed!!!
        } 
        catch (IOException ex) 
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    @FXML void handlePrimaryViewButton(ActionEvent actionEvent)
    {
        System.out.println(spSubsceneHolder.getChildren().get(0) == vbFirstsubsceneRoot);
        
        if(spSubsceneHolder.getChildren().get(0) == vbFirstsubsceneRoot)
        {
            Task<Long> getSumLongRunningTask = longRunningProcess();
            getSumLongRunningTask.setOnRunning((onRunningEvent) -> {
                taConsole.appendText("Long running Task is running!\n");
            });
            getSumLongRunningTask.setOnSucceeded(onSucceededEvent->{
                taConsole.appendText("Long running Task is complete!\n");
                taConsole.appendText("The sum is " + getSumLongRunningTask.getValue()+ "!\n");
                taConsole.appendText("Loading subscene two!\n");
                
                loadSecondsubsceneController();
            });
            
            Thread thread = new Thread(getSumLongRunningTask);
            thread.setDaemon(true);
            thread.start();
        }       
        else if(spSubsceneHolder.getChildren().get(0) == vbSecondsubsceneRoot)
        {
            //Do something!
        }
        else
        {
            //Do something!
        }        
    }    
    
    private Task<Long> longRunningProcess()
    {
        Task<Long> longRunningProcessTask = new Task<Long>() {
            @Override
            protected Long call() throws Exception {
                //The long running task sums the digits from 0 to n
                long sum = 0;
                for(int i = 0; i <= 100000; i++)
                {
                    sum += i;
                    System.out.println("Long running task is running!");
                }
                
                return sum;
            }
        };
        
        return longRunningProcessTask;        
    }
}
```

---

**FirstsubsceneController**

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;

/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class FirstsubsceneController implements Initializable {
//Use if needed to load Model!!!
//    private DataModel model ;
//    
//    public void initModel(DataModel model) {
//        if (this.model != null) {
//            throw new IllegalStateException("Model can only be initialized once");
//        }
//        this.model = model ;
//    }
//    
    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    
    
}
```

---

**SecondsubsceneController**

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;

/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class SecondsubsceneController implements Initializable {

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }      
}
```

---

**primary.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="720.0" prefWidth="1080.0" spacing="20.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/18" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sed.test.stackoverflowtestareafxfxml.PrimaryController">
   <children>
      <Label text="Primary View" />
      <HBox prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
         <children>
            <TextArea fx:id="taConsole" prefHeight="598.0" prefWidth="346.0" />
            <StackPane fx:id="spSubsceneHolder" prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="200.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
      <Button fx:id="btnPrimaryView" onAction="#handlePrimaryViewButton" text="Submit Form" />
   </children>
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
   </padding>
</VBox>
```

---

**firstsubscene.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" style="-fx-background-color: yellow;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/18" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sed.test.stackoverflowtestareafxfxml.FirstsubsceneController">
   <children>
      <Label text="First Subscene">
         <VBox.margin>
            <Insets top="10.0" />
         </VBox.margin>
      </Label>
      <StackPane prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="200.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
   </children>
</VBox>
```

---

**secondsubscene.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" style="-fx-background-color: green;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/18" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Label text="Second Subscene View" />
      <StackPane prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="200.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
   </children>
</VBox>
```

---

**Output**

[image]

---

**Note**

After reading your post again, you may not want to switch subscenes. You may want to do a list of `Tasks`. If so, you can start each new process in the previous process `setOnSucceeded`, or you can look into `SequentialTransition`.

Answer (score 0):

There are `Stage` 'life-cycle' events that you can influence by providing them with a custom `EventHandler`:

- Shown
- Showing
- Hidden
- Hiding
- Close request

An example of how to execute logic when a stage is in the process of hiding (or being closed):

```
stage.setOnHiding(event -> {
  System.out.println("Stage hiding");
});
```

Another example that demonstrates logic being executed when the stage is shown:

```
stage.setOnShown(event -> {
  System.out.println("Stage Shown");
});
```

For more information, please see the JavaFX lifecycle documentation:
https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Stage.html https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.base/javafx/event/EventHandler.html https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/Initializable.html

Comment: Hi @CodeDead: 

I just re-formatted the code, so it's more concise.

I used your suggestion, however, I get the **same behaviour** with the exception that it shows a `blank scene`. Then you have to wait for the whole process to finish to actually see what happened.

I've tried `setOnShown((event)` and `setOnShowing((event)`. I also move the event creation around, even to the initialize method. But having it where it is actually does something, eventhou it's not the target behavior.

Comment: Some links here are outdated.  JavaFX 8 is obsolete.  Current supported versions are 17 LTS or 20, which is [documented at openjfx](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20).

Comment: HI jewelsea... Thanks for your comments...Yes, indeed I agree with you and not use the JavaFX Thread for long process. But the question remains... How can I detect that the form is loaded and ready (JavaFX Thread finished) so I can trigger the long process.....I've tried a Pre-loader, but (1) it uses the JavaFx thread and (2) it doesn't change the behaviour: it'll show the form when Everything is done.... I need to run a export process that will send a message to the JavaFx form when a process has started or finished, so that the user is aware of what is happening.

Comment: I've also tried "Platform.runLater" but it waits for the whole process to finish to show the form.